# управление сайтом через телеграм бота

Tags: python, html, css, веб-программирование, telegram-bot

Я делаю сайт и для более удобного обновления новостей планирую сделать телеграм бота:
выбираешь команду 'добавить новость' - скидываешь фото для новости, пишешь текст - отправляешь и бот добавляет новость на сайт

я думаю как то добавлять div'ы и в них писать новости с фотографиями
и еще добавить функцию удаления новости в бота (чтоб не перегрузить сайт кучей новостей или если какая то ошибка в тексте)

как можно сделать чтобы бот редактировал сайт и добавлял новость, а так же ее удалял?

P.S я пишу на питоне и в вебе совсем новичок, поэтому код желательно сделать на питоне а не на js

Comment: Вы описали свои планы и задачи, но забыли задать вопрос

Comment: А как бы вы делали это без бота? Ну вот и с ботом так же. Например, сделайте api для добавления и удаления новостей (не забудьте про авторизацию) и пусть бот в этот api ходит. Если возникнут проблемы, возвращайтесь сюда с конкретными вопросами.